# Best Practise - Should an empty state message have a full stop?

Tags: empty

An empty state that is a blank screen such as:

- "You have no messages"
- "No Games Available"

Should these have sentences have full stops?  What is the best practise for using full stops in design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to refer to popular applications that have proven themselves to be successful. As you can see, all applications bellow have the full stop.

**Facebook:**

[image]

**Telegram:**

[image]

**Gmail:**

[image]

Comment: Absolutely, I thought more likely than not full stops would be the case. But I scrolled through these apps https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mobile-app-empty-state-designs/ and there was more of a mixture.

Comment: On a side note I don't like the Telegram '...' I think it reminds me too much of a a loading bar with '...' and that could put slightly uncertainty in the users head.

Answer (score -1):

Our users need to retrieve information fast. For the question you given here I think in this scenario full stop is not the best idea. Our readers need to retrieve information fast. We can use **Exclamation Mark( ! )** or **Speech Mark ( " " )**

**Full Stop is helped especially if you have a lot of content. It did not help when you want to build rapport or deal with a sensitive issue or some empty** state for example:

1) "NO INTERNET CONNECTION" 
2) "NO GAMES AVAILABLE"

Comment: AND ALL CAPS IS USUALLY DISCOURAGED BECAUSE IT IS MUCH HARDER TO READ